# How to responsive widget page with masonry layout and specific order of widgets?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

I want to be able to render widgets (boxes, from here on) of different heights but with specific placements, they will vary depending on the page data (which boxes should render, and which order + height can be different)

I don't want any unnecessary space between or within boxes. This is the hard part! Since if placing boxes in rows, a row is a fixed height (usually the height of the tallest item on that row).

Here are two examples of what I want to achieve:

[image: example-1] and [image: example-2]

example-1 and example-2

Note the different heights on the boxes, and how column 1 only has box-1.

Only way I know is possible to do this is to have two columns (left and right) and then flexbox render the boxes within each column. Fine.

But, here comes the problem:

On smaller screen size (mobile), I want only one column. And I want the boxes to be in the same column, **so that I can arrange the order of them**. For example like this:

[image: example-3]

Example-3

Note how box-3 is pushed to the top.

## WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED

I have been experimenting with having to different renders completely, depending on breakpoint, but that makes the boxes re-render when changing window width, which is not ideal since that will have them flicker or even re-fetch the data.

- pureCSS: css-grid, won't work with usual row since that is a fixed height. Could work having two strict columns, and then each box will have their own row within it to render flexibly inside them. BUT that would require re-rendering boxes when going to mobile view (1 column) since ordering won't work (box 1 is separated from box 2-3-4)
- pureCSS: flexbox, would also require two separate flexbox-containers (one for each column) which won't order items
- [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/): only problem is won't let me order items!! And also with fill the first column with box-2 (see example). otherwise works great.
- [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout): works splendid, BUT, has a problem with dynamicHeight of boxes. Say if the data is huge then the widget/component height is stuck.

I am using react, if that matters. Perhaps I could have two different renders (desktop 2 columns / mobile 1 column) if there would be a way to render the same box but in different places of the dom (and thus not make them re-render)?

Any help in understanding this problem better is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CSS columns would be an easy way to achieve this. Having the second element break into the second column, even if there would still be space available below the first element, can easily be achieved using `break-before: column`:

```css
ul {
  columns: 2
}

li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  break-before: column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

And to have it look different on mobile, use `flex` there instead, so that you can use `order` to move element #3 to the front.

EDIT: `break-before: column` appears not work work in Firefox yet.

Different approach: The elements are put into two container elements, to be able to easily get the desktop view.

And for the mobile view, you "dissolve" those wrappers using `display: contents` - then the items will again behave as if they were children of just *one* parent (`.outer`), and you can use `order` again:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.outer div {
  display: contents
}

.foo {
  order: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>2</span>
    <span class="foo">3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"can easily be achieved using break-before: column"_ - oh, I am just realizing that Firefox apparently does not support this yet.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, this solves part of the problem but `columns` does not allow for ordering of items (see picture example-3).

Comment: That's why I said to use flex _instead_ of columns for mobile :-)

Comment: I edited the question and added a different approach, that _does_ use two wrapper elements for the desktop view - which for the mobile view get dissolved using `display: contents`

Comment: Thanks for you effort CBroe, this does not work as I need it to work. Gave me some ideas to how to proceed with changing display: x, when in mobile. But no solution yet.

Comment: @Jammar Why not? The second one, does exactly what you said you wanted - show the items that are grouped as [1], [2,3,4] as [3,1,2,4] for the mobile view. And the desktop layout you want, can simply be achieved by making the two containers display next to each other using flex.